# Symfony2: Get Route Path

Tags: php, symfony, path, routes

With the command `$this->generateUrl($route);` inside a Controller I can get the URL of the Route.

However, I only want to retrieve the last part of it (as specified in *routing.yml*).

For example, instead of `/web/app_dev.php/$path` I just want to return `/$path`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$route = $this->get('router')->getRouteCollection()->get('routeName');
if ($route)
    echo $route->getPath();
```

You also could take a look at `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\RouterDebugCommand` (class responsible for `router:debug` console command).

Otherwise: `str_replace` (or  `substr`) on the first part would also be an option

Comment: This is exactly what I've been searching for...Thank you!

Comment: This works, but it's important to mention that you should not use getRouteCollection() as it worsens the performance: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/6710

Answer (score 1):

```
$request->getPathInfo();
```

You want to get it from router or request ?